# previous value in function apply R Stduio

Tags: r, apply

i have problem with substraction 2 value from data frame in apply function. I took stock timeseries and try to substract value in time i and i-1:

```
library(data.table)
do_apply <- rep(NA,nrow(DATA))

do_apply$close <- DATA$Zamkniecie


funkcja <- function(close){
  close_lag_1 <- shift(x=close,
                            n = 1,
                            type = 'lag',
                            fill=0)
  close <- close - close_lag_1
  return(zamkniecie)
}

sapply(do_apply$close, funkcja)
```

Comment: Can you use `diff` instead? That is, replace your `sapply(..)` with just `diff(do_apply$close)`.

Comment: Subjects should accurately identify the essence of the problem.  This problem is a pure R problem and is not specific to RStudio so the subject should not refer to it.  You can mention that you are using RStudio in the question in case you think that may be relevant although it appears not in this case.  Also DATA is undefined.  This is needed so that others can run the code.  There is some info on asking questions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.